# Get current url when you're in a iframe

Tags: php

I have made a page that contains an iframe.

The page that is in the iframe has to get the current url from the page containing the iframe.

Does anyone know what I have to do in order to do this?

Comment: parent and child iframe on same domain ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: no a page that contains an iframe <iframe .....  then the iframe gos to the page blabla.php in the page blabla.php there must be a script that gets the url form the page where the iframe is in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take: a Javascript Approach and a PHP approach.

### JAVASCRIPT

*Only works if the iframe is on the same domain as the parent page or you've set XXS rules that allows the child domain to access the parent domain*

Assuming that you've met the above criteria, you can access the parent page url using Javascript by grabbing the `location.href` property of the parent window:

```
alert('The parent window url is: '+window.top.location.href);
```

You can also use `window.parent.location.href`.

if the iframe is a different domain than the parent then this will not work due to cross-domain scripting rules unless you've overridden them. If you control both domains you may be able to create cross-domain scripting rules for the parent domain that specifically allow access from the iframe's domain (http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). Once this is done you can use the code above.

### PHP Approach

*Works, but relies on you controlling the parent page*

Alternately, if the parent page has a static URL, you can just pass that as a `_GET` variable to the iframe:

**Parent**

```
<iframe src="/iframe/url.php?parent_src=<?php echo urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>"></iframe>
```

**Child**

```
<?php $parent_url = urldecode($_GET['parent_src']); ?>
```

And you can now work with the parent URL in the `$parent_url` variable:

```
<? echo "The parent's URL is: http://thedomain.com".$parent_url;?>
```

Comment: tnks that helpt but i am not so good in java so can jou say how to make a php variable from it if this is possible

Comment: Are you familiar with AJAX?

Comment: no i am sorry but the only thing i now is html php and css i am 14 years old :/

Comment: If you're working with a Javascript framework like jQuery you don't have to do much work: get the parent URL using Javascript, then pass that to a PHP script using the [`.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) functions and store the URL in a PHP `_SESSION` variable so you can work with it. However, I've also added a simpler approach in my answer that avoids JS altogether so long as you control both domains and the parent has a static URL.

Comment: ya i know that but i want the code in the page on the iframe so if someone past that iframe to that page i can get the url when the page where the iframe i cant access

Comment: ok i dont know what you mean can you give an example? :/

Comment: Did you see my updated answer? Use the PHP approach... it's much easier to implement. When you embed the iframe just including the parent URL as a `_GET` variable in the iframe URL (I gave an example). You can then work with the parent URL in PHP by echoing `urldecode($_GET['parent_src'])` (keep in mind that it will be missing the *http://domainnate.com* parent of the URL, but you can just append that.

Comment: ya i know that but i want the code in the page on the iframe so if someone past that iframe to a page i can get the url when the page where the iframe is i cant access

Comment: but for now that anser is ok so thankyou